# C# dictionary key as dictionary

Tags: c#

My dictionary key is another dictionary.How can I view if my dictonary("games") ContainsKey "myname" for example ?
I have something like this :

```
Dictionary<string,List<ChatClient>> rooms = new Dictionary<string, List<ChatClient>>();
Dictionary<Dictionary<string, List<ChatClient>>, IGame> games = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, List<ChatClient>>, IGame>();

public void CreateAGame(string roomName, IGame game) {
     if (rooms.ContainsKey(roomName)) {
         games.Add(rooms, game);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want a hierarchy of

```
Games
    ChatRooms
```

Depending on actual requirements you'd probably want to store actual chat rooms in one dictionary, and "index" of chat rooms per games in another dictionary. Accessing the actual chat becomes 2 step process:

1. Get List of Chat Rooms per game from _chatRoomsPerGame dictionary
2. Get the Actual Chat Room from _allChatRooms dictionary.

While it is possible to create your own object to host a dictionary and override GetHashKey to create a dictionary with a key of other dictionary, I doubt that is what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to work: two identically composed dictionaries will not compare as equal to each other ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/7krwFy)).

```
var a = new Dictionary<string,string> {{"a","a"}};
var b = new Dictionary<string,string> {{"a","a"}};
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
```

In general, you should not key your dictionary on anything mutable. Make a method that converts a dictionary to a "canonical `string` representation", and use that `string` as a key in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ContainsDictKey(Dictionary<Dictionary<string, List<ChatClient>>, IGame> games, string key)
{
    foreach(var l in games)
    {
        if(l.Key.ContainsKey(key))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this is good idea, the key should be immutable, whereas Dictionary isn't immutable.

Comment: It's not a good idea at all, see the @dasblinkenlight answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
games.Keys.SelectMany(x => x.Keys).Contains("myname")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be:

If we have:

```
 Dictionary<Dictionary<string, List<ChatClient>>, IGame> games = 
               new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, List<ChatClient>>, IGame>();
```

and in some function

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByName(string myName) {
    return games.Keys.Where(x=>x.Contains("myName"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var innerDictionary = rooms.Keys.Where(innerdict => innerdict.ContainsKey(roomName)));
```